# How to use getJSON sending data from prompt var to PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

I Created a button that when onclick he delivering a prompt message in order
The user will enter a free text.
Now I need to use this free text and pass it as var input with GET method to external PHP in my system.
I have tried using the getJSON method to do the following :

```
       '<button onclick="SendFreeMSG()">Test MSG </button>

                <p id="testMSG"></p>

                <script>
                function SendFreeMSG() {
                    var InputMessage= prompt("Please enter your Message", "Write down your message Here");

                    if (InputMessage!= null) {
                    document.getElementById("testMSG").innerHTML = "Your message is: " + InputMessage + " "  ;
                    $.getJSON("sending_msg_to_user.php?userinput=" . $InputMessage ["userinput"] .
                    }

                }
                </script>' ;
```

The scrpit is working fine without the getJSON row, but when I tried it with that row nothing happen.

----- Addition ----
Here is another part of my code with click button and $getJSON
In this part it is working well:

```
                          '<button onclick="' .
                                        "if (confirm('sending message ?')) {
                             var activeValue = $(this).siblings('.all_users_active_value');" . 
                                            "var activeCaption = $(this).siblings('.all_users_active_caption');"  .
                                            "$.getJSON('sending_general_msg.php?General=" . $rowData['General'] . 
                                              "&active=' + (activeValue.html() == '1' ? '0' : '1'), " . 
                                               "function(data) { " . 
                                                "activeValue.html(data.active);" . 
                                                "activeCaption.html(data.active == 1 ? 'Active' : 'Inactive')" . 
                                            "})
                            } else {
                               alert('sending message cancelled')
                            };" .
                                            "return false;". 
                                        '"> Sending new message </button>';
```

I will appreciate any help with that matter

Abraham

Comment: What is the code of or what are you doing in sending_msg_to_user.php

Comment: why is that all in a `'...';` string? Are you trying to generate html in php? If so, that'll never work - `'`-quoted strings do **NOT** interpolate variables, and PHP is not recursively embeddable.

Comment: @bicho the php is wating with $_GET to the "userinput"

Comment: @Abraham and then you encode to json?

Comment: @Marc B I didn't know how to get the var ImputMessage to I thought this syntax will do the job right

Comment: @bicho no I am not. I just wanted to pass some how the input from that prompt message to the $_GET inside the external PHP
BTW, if there is another way to do it more correctly I would be happy to know

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ajax to send sometime from java to a php file. below is a tutorial on how to use ajax.

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass the input value to another php, you must to use Ajax in jQuery, I hope this example will help you

```
$.ajax({
        type:"get",
        url:"sending_msg_to_user.php",
        data:"InputMessage="+InputMessage,
        beforeSend: function(){
                        $('#some_div').html('<img src="img/Loading.gif"/> Sending Data');                           
                    },
        success:function(data){
             alert(data);
              $('#some_div').html('');
        }
     });
```

If you have an echo in sending_msg_to_user.php you could see in an alert message tha value of inpu in prompt

Comment: Thanks @bicho I will give it a try.
BTW look at the example I edit on top in that part of the code it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Your $.getJSON request is poorly formed.  If you paste that function directly into your favorite JavaScript console and hit 'enter', you would see the error:

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
     at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:905:140)
     at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:838:34)
     at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:694:21)
```

Try something like:

```
 $.getJSON('sending_msg_to_user.php?userinput=' + InputMessage);
```